# multiselect dropdown in ui-grid cell template not rendering properly after scroll

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angular ui-grid and creating a editable cell template with multiselect dropdown.
I have tried [this](http://brianhann.com/ui-grid-and-multi-select/) tutorial but it is not working.
I am using simple multiselect dropdown but customized it so that it opens on button click. I followed [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/Re7E7y38M2WpkzAJyL5p?p=preview) plnkr to style the multiselect dropdown to open above the grid and overlap below cells.

```
.ui-grid-cell .ui-grid-cell-contents {
  overflow: visible;
}
.ui-grid-cell-focus{
  overflow: visible;
}
```

I set the positon of the celltemplate as absolute.

[image]

But when I scroll down the styles doesn't work. For the rows in last it doesn't even open.

[image]

How do I solve this problem please help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be due to table height. Increasing the table height worked for me.